# Firmware self update MCU level support: MK20DX256VLH7 or MIMXRT1062DVL6A

Tags: firmware, update

I've been reading MK20DX256VLH7 [datasheet](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/K20P64M72SF1RM.pdf) for a day and still didn't find any description about built-in mechanisms for intrinsic firmware update. I mean stuff that helps (allows) currently running firmware update itself. e.g. 2 banks of flash feature in SAM3x8e that can be switched and etc.

1. Is it possible with these devices firmware to be updated by firmware itself?
2. This device MK20DX256VLH7 has 256Kb flash memory for firmware. Is it possible to overwrite the program flash while firmware is running? (suppose isn't due to it's executed from flash)

MK20DX256VLH7 has SPI based 'EzPort' that is the way of program it. The programming process is controlled by EzPort protocol. I would like my firmware control the update and just receive the firmware via UART, I2C etc. as the raw binary array.

E.g. ESP8266 provide special command that copies a memory to zero address and reboot. I'm asking for same features in these MCUs.

Comment: I think you have to write that yourself. Even if it included bootloader in ROM, I don't think the bootloader default would necessarily do that.

Comment: You need to write you own (or copy an open-source) bootloader and program it into the lower *x* sectors of flash. You'll also need to write (or copy) some sort of application to run on your PC to connect & talk to this bootloader to download and (re)write application firmware. As a starting point, you might find Arduino support for your device to give you a head-start.

Comment: I already searched the web for an open source projects on this subject, nothing found for this MCU type. I understand I have to write this on my own and I have such experience, but I need to find out whether MCU level support of self update exists.

Comment: The Kinetis series MCUs generally don't have any kind of DFU rom (like SAMBA on the Atmel devices). NXP offers KBOOT https://www.nxp.com/design/software/development-software/mcuxpresso-software-and-tools/mcuboot-mcu-bootloader-for-nxp-microcontrollers:MCUBOOT?&tid=vanKBOOT